# Modify image extension to use later

Tags: django, image, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL in django to crop image and save the copy of it:

```
     image.save(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..'))+kid.image_url +".thumbnail","JPEG")
```

Image thumbnail is saved temporarily and can be accessed by:

```
    kid.image_url+".thumbnail"
```

Problem is I want to save it in original format, not the thumbnail and be able to access it later. Is there any better solution, like to put "_thumbnail" after image and be able to access it by kid.image_url+"_thumbnail".

Comment: Why don't you save the original image with the base filename as is, say "image.jpg" and thumbnails as "image.thumb.jpg"?

Comment: kid.image_url contains "example.jpg". How do I change it to "example.thumb.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can change "example.jpg" to "example.thumb.jpg":

```
import os
filename, extn = os.path.splitext(kid.image_url)
thumb_filename = filename + ".thumb" + extn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need something special, I suggest you use sorl-thumbnail application. You save the image in original size and sorl-thumbnail creates the thumbnail for you in template. The usage is very simple:

```
{% load thumbnail %}

{% thumbnail object.image "100x100" as im %}<img src="{{ im.url }}">{% endthumbnail %}
```

If you change the thumbnail size later, new thumbnails will be created automatically, so you don't need anything to do .